# Weird error in xcode (static member center cannot be used ...)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a code in Swift v5.1.3:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginRequest: Codable {
    var username = String();
    var password = String();
}

struct LoginResponse: Codable {
    var success = Bool();
    var token = String();
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var username: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""

    func handleClientError(err: Error) {
        print("REQUEST ERROR!")
    }

    func handleServerError(urlResponse: URLResponse) {
        print("RESPONSE ERROR!")
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .center) {

            Image("logo")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fit)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 100.0, alignment: .topLeading)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 100, leading: 50, bottom: 0, trailing: 50))

            Text("LOGIN")
                .font(.custom("AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin", size: 25))
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))

            TextField("Username", text: $username)
                .padding()
                .background(Color("flash-white"))
                .font(.custom("AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin", size: 25))
                .border(Color.init(hex: "dddddd"))

            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                .padding()
                .background(Color("flash-white"))
                .font(.custom("AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin", size: 25))
                .border(Color.init(hex: "dddddd"))

            Button(action: {
                var newRequestParams = LoginRequest(username: username, password: password)
                var jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(value: newRequestParams)

                var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1.0.0/login")!)
                request.httpMethod = "POST"
                request.httpBody = jsonData

                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

                    // Was there an error in request?
                    if error != nil {
                        self.handleClientError(err: error!)
                        return
                    }

                    // Response code is 2XX?
                    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                        self.handleServerError(urlResponse: response!)
                        return
                    }

                    // Has mime type fine?
                    guard let mime = response!.mimeType, mime == "application/json" else {
                        print("Wrong MIME type!")
                        return
                    }

                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                        print(json)
                    } catch {
                        print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }

                    // Do something...
                }

                task.resume()
            }) {
                Text("LOGIN")
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 15, leading: 100, bottom: 15, trailing: 100))
                .background(Color.init(hex: "e5323c"))
                    .font(.custom("AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin", size: 25))
                .cornerRadius(4.0)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .scaledToFill()
            }
            .background(Color("flash-white"))
            .cornerRadius(4.0)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))

        }
        .padding()
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:
Static member 'center' cannot be used on instance of type 'HorizontalAlignment'

If I comment out the following lines, the error is gone and the code build will be successful:

```
var jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(value: newRequestParams)
request.httpBody = jsonData
```

I can't see the connection between the error and the lines of code, can you somebody help me what the heck happening here?

Thank you,
R

---

Comment: Your view code should *not* contain stuff like this. Your UI should know absolutely nothing about JSON, URL requests, mimetype, or any of that.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica With SwiftUI, I usually add a function at the bottom of the struct, or have an `@ObservableObject` reference - what is the "correct" way?

Comment: Yep, a function at the bottom of the struct is fine. But even that function shouldn't know anything about JSON or URL requests. You should have something like a `AuthorizationController` which handles all the stuff related to tracking the user, who's logged in, log-in/log-out, switching users, etc., which delegate to something like a `LoginService` object, which handles all the http stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't know what just happened

What happened is that you said something nonsensical and the compiler reported an error. Then you fixed the nonsense and the code compiled.

The confusing part is only that the compiler reported the "wrong" error. It has to do with complicated behind-the-scenes function builder parsing of the VStack initializer's function parameter. This often causes simple errors to be reflected as "bogus" errors reported in a different place, making your real error hard to track down. That's just the way SwiftUI is.

If you had made this same mistake outside the SwiftUI context, you would have seen this error message:

> Extraneous argument label 'value:' in call

And that is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the correct explanation. The invalid error message caused the confusion for me.

Comment: Yeah, you can see sort of what happened: we couldn't parse the stuff in the VStack's curly braces and the error got "reflected" all the way back on to `VStack (alignment: .center)` at the start.

Answer (score 0):

OK,  I changed the code to the following, and the error is gone. I don't know what just happened:

```
var jsonData: Data = Data();
                do {
                    jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(newRequestParams)
                }
                catch {
                    return ;
                }
```

Comment: You just discarded the error, if one were to be raised. I guarantee you this will bite you in the ass.